# Ubuntu home is empty after fsck

Tags: ubuntu, fsck

I have ubuntu 20.04, I ran into `initramfs` screen, then after some search I executed

```
fsck /dev/sda6 -y
```

when it's done the GUI is up, but I can not login with my user so I decided to use terminal mode and there I could login but I realized the `/home` directory is empty.

Output of command

```
df -h | grep -e 'sda'
```

shows that 73 percent for /dev/sda6 is used.

How can I return my files back to home?

Comment: Was `/dev/sda6` mounted at `/home`? If so, did you remount it?

Comment: did you mount `/home` in a separate partition? have it mounted?, `fsck` could not be issue.

Comment: @HosseinVatani I am not sure if /home was mounted in a seperate partition.

Comment: @rahram,run `ls /` and `ls /home`, consider the result. if nothing as result so use _/etc/fstab_,  `blkid` and watch `mount | grep sd` to find which partitioned not mounted.